# volume not found or not mounted when trying to umount

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to detach [Amazon EBS Volume from an Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-detaching-volume.html), and I can't figure out why the filesystem can't be found/isn't mounted.

On my EBS Volumes, the attachment information shows:

```
(Instance1):/dev/sdh (attached)
(Instance1):/dev/sdo (attached)
(Instance1):/dev/sdo (attached)
(Instance1):/dev/sdj (attached)
(Instance1):/dev/sdi (attached)
(Instance1):/dev/sdn (attached)
(Instance1):/dev/sdm (attached)
(Instance1):/dev/sda1 (attached)
(Instance1):/dev/sdl (attached)
```

Running `fdisk -l` on the instance, I get:

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 16.1 GB, 16106127360 bytes
Disk /dev/xvdh: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
Disk /dev/xvdm: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
Disk /dev/xvdi: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
Disk /dev/xvdn: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
Disk /dev/xvdj: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
Disk /dev/xvdo: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
Disk /dev/xvdk: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
Disk /dev/xvdl: 156.8 GB, 156766306304 bytes
Disk /dev/md127: 1254.1 GB, 1254122061824 bytes
```

Trying to `umount`:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-22 ~]# umount -d /dev/xvdm
umount: /dev/xvdm: not mounted
[root@ip-10-0-0-22 ~]# umount -d /dev/sdm
umount: /dev/sdm: not found
```

`mount`:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-22 ~]# mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/md127 on /vertica/data type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
```

How can I delete the underlying filesystems?

---

> Delete what underlying filesystems? Also, could you cut-and-paste the output of cat /proc/mdstat into your question? –  MadHatter

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-22 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0]
md127 : active raid0 xvdj[2] xvdn[6] xvdl[4] xvdh[0] xvdm[5] xvdi[1] xvdk[3] xvdo[7]
      1224728576 blocks super 1.2 1024k chunks

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: ...because the drives aren't mounted?

Comment: Delete what underlying filesystems?  Also, could you cut-and-paste the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` into your question?

Comment: Oh wait, read that better...you have an `mdadm` RAID setup. Use those tools to release drives from the array (don't do this unless you know what you're doing!!!!)

Comment: @NathanC pardon my ignorance, but what are the disks listed?

Comment: @MadHatter updated.

Comment: Those are the individual "parts" to the `/dev/md127` device you have (indeed, the drives all add up to that amount). You have either a RAID or LVM setup there, so traditional tools won't cut it.

Comment: Do you want the contents of `/vertica/data` or not?  If not, say so clearly, and we can tell you how to dismantle it and free those drives.  If you do, **stop messing around with the drives immediately, or you risk trashing the array!**

Comment: @MadHatter I have very little knowledge in this area. I'm not familiar with how AWS creates the arrays. I want to detach these volumes to reduce the total space used. This is a non-critical development environment.

Comment: I repeat my question: **do you want the data that's currently stored in `/vertica/data`**?  We can certainly guide you through deleting the data and freeing up the drives, but I for one would like a **very clear statement** that you don't want the data before we do so.

Comment: @MadHatter I do **not want** the data that's stored in `/vertica/data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you've been clear that you don't want the data (thank you, it's good to be clear about things like that).  Unmount the filesystem

`umount /vertica/data`

Then stop the metadevice

`mdadm -S /dev/md127`

That should be enough to free up the devices so they become detached from the host instance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the drives are mounted into the filesysem, try unmounting the filesystem mount point

```
umount /path/to/mount/point/for/xvdm
```

This should work under most circumstances whereas there are times when unmounting the device will fail

> The  umount command detaches the file system(s) mentioned from the file
>          hierarchy.  A file system is specified by giving the directory where it
>          has  been  mounted.  Giving the special device on which the file system
>          lives may also work, but is obsolete, mainly because it  will  fail  in
>          case this device was mounted on more than one directory.

---

You've updated your question but the answer is basically the same. You have a number of devices that have been made into a RAID-0 array. If you really want to unmount this then

```
umount /vertica/data
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You have a RAID or LVM setup that's simply merging all the disks into one big disk:

`/dev/md127 on /vertica/data type ext4 (rw)`

All those drives are critical to that mount point. If you *must* for some reason release a drive for one reason or another, do so with the same tools used to create the array.

***MAKE A BACKUP BEFORE YOU DO THIS!*** Countless bytes have been lost due to improper array management.